# ¿Cuál es el pronombre posesivo de "vos"?

Tags: pronombres, voseo, posesivos

El pronombre posesivo de "vosotros" es "vuestro".  ¿Cuál es el pronombre posesivo de "vos"? He visto varios sites que mostrar la pareja de "vosotros/vuestro", pero solamente mostrar "tú/tuyo" y nunca mostrar "vos".

Yo sé que se usa "vos" para "tú" en los países que usar voseo. Por lo tanto ¿es que se usa "tuyo" para el posesivo de "vos"?

Y si se usa "tuyo", ¿hubo un momento histórico en el que se usara una palabra diferente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Información obtenida de las páginas que aparecen más abajo*;

En ellas podrás encontrar todas las dudas respecto al "voseo", al ser un tema con bastantes matices te dejo estas dos páginas, que sin duda, contestarán a tus preguntas.

- **El voseo en América Latina y en España**

https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/pronombres-y-determinantes/voseo

- **Diccionario panhispánico de dudas**

https://www.rae.es/dpd/voseo

---

....

*La forma de cortesía usted ha sufrido muchas modificaciones a lo largo de la historia. Comenzó siendo «Vuesa merced», donde vuesa significa vuestra. El uso, y el mal uso, de esta fórmula durante años derivó en numerosas contracciones que han quedado documentadas en los textos literarios: «vuessa merçed», «vuesarçed», «vuarçed», «vuaçed», «vusted», hasta llegar finalmente a la fórmula actual: «usted»*.

......

Como posesivo, se emplea la forma "vuestro". Admiro vuestro coraje, señor.

Los adjetivos referidos a la persona o personas a quienes nos dirigimos han de establecer la concordancia correspondiente en género y número.

*Vos, don Pedro, sois caritativo; Vos, bellas damas, sois ingeniosas*.

El pronombre "vos" sustituye a las formas personales de "tú y ti". Sin embargo, los pronombres **te**, **tu** y **tuyo** permanecen invariables.

*Sí, te hablo a vos. ¿Es este tu bolso?*

*Vos te levantaste de mal humor.*

**Diccionario panhispánico de dudas**

*VOSEO. En términos generales, se denomina «voseo» el empleo de la forma pronominal vos para dirigirse al interlocutor*. Se distinguen:

1. *Voseo reverencial*
2. *Voseo dialectal americano*.

2.1. *Voseo pronominal y voseo verbal*.

2.1.1. *El «voseo pronominal» consiste en el uso de vos como pronombre de segunda persona del singular en lugar de tú y de ti. Vos se emplea como sujeto: «Puede que vos tengás razón*».

2.1.2. *El «voseo verbal» consiste en el uso de las desinencias verbales propias de la segunda persona del plural, más o menos modificadas, para las formas conjugadas de la segunda persona del singular: tú vivís, vos comés o comís.*

2.1.2.1. *Voseo verbal en los tiempos de presente*

2.1.2.2. *Voseo verbal en los tiempos de pasado*

....

Comment: Yo sé que es "voseo", pero parece a mi que dijiste que el posesivo de "vos" es "vuestro".  Pero ¿por qué? "Vos" es singular y "vuestro" se usar con el plural "vosotros", ¿no?

Comment: Como posesivo se emplea la forma "vuestro". Admiro vuestra valentía, señora. Los adjetivos referidos a la persona o personas a quienes nos dirigimos han de establecer la concordancia correspondiente en género y número. Vos, don Pedro, sois caritativo. Vos, bellas damas, sois ingeniosas. Por favor lea lo que le mande, los "voseos" se expresan de diferentes maneras en países distintos. Por ejemplo en el Voseo en Paraguay, La segunda persona del plural es "Ustedes". Así, en lugar de "vosotros sabéis", dicen, "ustedes saben".

Comment: El voseo es el uso del pronombre vos como segunda persona singular, utilizando la 5ª inflexión verbal (correspondiente a vosotros) habitualmente mezclada con la 2ª inflexión verbal (correspondiente a tú).  
Español/La conjugación/El voseo https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol/La_conjugaci%C3%B3n/El_voseo#:~:text=Voseo%20verbal%3A%20Es%20el%20uso,%3A%20te%2C%20tu%2C%20tuyo.

Comment: "Vos" singular "Usted", "Vos" plural "Ustedes". «vuessa merçed», «vuesarçed», «vuarçed», «vuaçed», «vusted», hasta llegar finalmente a la fórmula actual. «usted»/ustedes

Comment: "Vos" no tiene plural, ya es plural. Antiguamente se utilizaba como tratamiento de respeto referido a una 3ª ps. del sing., pero con verbo en plural (porque es plural). Vos sois ingenioso. El atributo va en singular porque se refiere sólo a una persona, pero el verbo va en plural porque el sujeto, formalmente, también está (o es) plural. "Vos" es pronombre personal, viene a expresar "Tú y otros más" vendría del compuesto, "Vos y Otros". Vos, en el español antiguo era lo mismo que ahora decir Tú. Aplicado al plural "Vos, bellas damas, sois ingeniosas".

Comment: Pero como digo, sus modos , formación e influencia, incluso sobre el mismo verbo, es distinta según la zona.